# Use selenium to capture 'Did you mean' on google search page

Tags: python, selenium

If I type Johnkaranski in google search , 'Did you mean: John Kransky' appears on the top . I want the result of Did you mean to be returned by my google query function .

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
chromedriver = 'chrome/chromedriver.exe'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver,options=options)

def is_google_listing(query): 
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q={}".format(query))
    #try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of((By.ID, 'fprsl')))
    didumean = driver.find_element_by_id('fprsl')
    return didumean
    #except:
      #  return False
```

I have commented the try exept statements . I get errors . I found out that Did you mean is stored in id:fprsl

Comment: can you share what error you are getting?

Comment: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'is_displayed'

Comment: Sometimes I was getting error " Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="fprsl"]"}

Comment: I think the id is wrong I need to do it some other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
didumean=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.gL9Hy'))).text
```

Comment: What if I query correctly and no Did you mean appears ? I am using try except to return false but it takes time

Comment: try-except bock is fine. It only takes as much extra time as you define for your `wait`. It's set to 10 seconds at the moment, but you can reduce it.